# Как определить цветовой диапазон opencv (cv2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, цвета

Нашел в документации к CV2 следующее: что бы найти нужный цветовой диапазон нужно цвет привести к HSV через `cvtColor()`. Цветовой диапазон будет `[H-10, 100, 100]` и `[H+10,255,255]`. Решил попробовать, на определении синих дорожных знаков. Взял пипетку, нашел средний цвет знака в формате RGB, преобразовал его и нашел диапазоны, но результат очень далёк от корректного: вижу, что он распознаёт бледно-оранжевый  . Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку и буду очень благодарен, если в дополнение к ответу вы объясните как находить цветовые диапазоны в любых ситуациях

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("imgs/road_signs_2.jpg")

blue = np.uint8([[[20, 94, 191]]])

hsv_blue = cv2.cvtColor(blue, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)  # 107, 228, 191

print(hsv_blue)
l_blue = np.array([97, 100, 100])
d_blue = np.array([117, 255, 255])

objs = cv2.inRange(img, l_blue, d_blue)

cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("blue_signs", objs)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы применяете inRange к BGR картинке, а надо к HSV. Т.е. сначала преобразуйте картинку в HSV: hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) Затем уже objs = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, l_blue, d_blue)

Comment: @AlexAlex, огромное спасибо!